# Der Anteil "am" oder "im Unterricht"

Tags: preposition

Im folgenden Satz:

> Der Anteil des Handys am/im Unterricht muss steigen.

Sollte es "am" oder "im Unterricht" heißen?

Grundsätzlich zweifle ich daran, dass der Satz verstanden werden kann. Was ist ausdrücken möchte, ist, dass das Handy mehr Einzug in den Unterricht finden soll.

Comment: Dann schreib doch "Das Handy sollte im Unterricht mehr einbezogen werden."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind möglich und wohlgeformt.

> (1) Der Anteil des Handys im Unterricht soll steigen.
>
> (2) Der Anteil des Handys am Unterricht soll steigen.

Eine Bedeutungsunterscheidung wird man nicht zwangsläufig treffen müssen. Das heißt, in einem gegebenen Kontext (Lehrer unterhalten sich über moderne Unterrichtsformen) wären sie weitgehend gleichwertig.

Lediglich wenn man die beiden Sätze kontrastierend gegenüberstellt und somit eine Bedeutungsunterscheidung forciert, könnte man versucht sein zu unterscheiden zwischen folgenden Bedeutungsvarianten:

a) Das Handy soll mehr Mittel des Unterrichts werden.

b) Das Handy soll mehr Thema des Unterrichts werden.

Welcher von beiden Sätzen nun aber eher zu a oder zu b tendiert... darüber gerate ich, je länger ich drüber nachdenke, desto eher in Zweifel.

Machen wir eine weitere Probe:

> (3) Der Anteil der Chemie im Unterricht soll steigen.
>
> (4) Der Anteil der Chemie am Unterricht soll steigen.

Könnte man hier unterscheiden zwischen

a) Es soll mehr Chemie (= Chemikalien) im Unterricht eingesetzt werden

b) Es soll mehr Chemie Thema im Unterricht sein.

Leider kann ich's selber nicht beantworten. Ich habe nun schon zu viel in diese Sätze hineingeört und bin betriebstaub geworden.

Comment: Anteil ist immer **an/von** etwas. Der Ausdruck "der Anteil des Handys am Unterricht" stellt daher eine Einheit mit dem Kern "der Anteil am Unterricht" dar. "Der Anteil des Handys im Unterricht" ist dagegen keine Einheit, sondern "der Anteil des Handys" mit präpositionalem Attribut "im Unterricht". - Inhaltlich tun jedoch beide meinem Gehör ganz dolle weh. Denn der Ausdruck mit "an" impliziert, dass der Unterricht sich aus etwas zusammensetzt, wozu u.a. "Handy" gehört. Der Ausdruck mit "im" impliziert, dass ein Handy sinnvoll geteilt und in Teilen im Unterricht benutzt werden kann. Huch! :-)

Comment: @Min-Soo  Ich teile die Auffassung, dass die Sätze nicht das Beste sind, was die Dichtkunst in deutscher Sprache hervorgebracht hat, aber alltagstauglich sind sie doch. Ich teile nicht deine Kritik, dass hier von *Teilen von Handys* die Rede sein müsse. Du kannst auch sagen: *Der Anteil der Stillarbeit am Unterricht sollte größer werden* und solche Dinge. In der Tat ist hier die Rede davon, aus was sich der *Unterricht* zusammensetzt, nicht aus was sich ein Handy (oder die Stillarbeit) zusammensetzt.

Comment: *"Der Anteil der Stillarbeit am Unterricht..."* und *"Der Anteil der Chemie am Unterricht..."* ist mit *"Der Anteil des Handys am Unterricht..."* nicht zu vergleichen. Stillarbeit ist eine *Tätigkeit*, und der Unterricht setzt sich durchaus aus Tätigkeiten zusammen. Chemie ist eine Wissenschaft oder ein *Fach*, und der Unterricht setzt sich durchaus aus Fächern zusammen. *Handy* ist dagegen ein *Gebrauchsgegenstand*, und der Unterricht setzt sich eben **nicht** aus Gegenständen zusammen, höchstens aus ihrem Gebrauch/ihrer Nutzung.

Answer (score 4):

Du möchtest ausdrücken, “dass das Handy mehr Einzug im Unterricht finden soll“? Dann schreibe doch

> Das Handy sollte mehr Einzug *in den* Unterricht finden.

Zumindest kann ein Handy weder an noch in etwas einen Anteil haben.

Answer (score 2):

Der Erklärung nach siehe die Antwort von @Björn Friedrich.

Als Formulierungen, die näher an Deinem Satz sind, schlage ich vor

> Die Nutzung des Handys im Unterricht muss steigen.
>   Der Anteil der Handynutzung am Unterricht muss steigen.